# Rails 7 link_to show action without database connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails 7 app I've got Payments list from which the data comes from an external API, they are not stored in DB, like below:

```
  # payments_controller.rb

  def index
    @payments = client.payments(user_id: current_user.payment_platform_id)
  end
```

Which I display in the view:

```
# payments/index.html.erb
<table>
  <tbody>
    <% @payments.each do |payment| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= payment.id %></td>
        <td><%= payment.amount %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Now I want to add `link_to` which will redirect user to the show action of that particular payment - in simple words to the `payments#show`. Additionally, pass that `payment` to the params to be available as `params[:payment]` inside the controller show action. Like below:

```
# payments_controller.rb
def show
  @payment = params[:payment]
end

# payments/index.html.erb
<tbody>
  <% @payments.each do |payment| %>
    <tr>
      other stuff (...)
      <td>
        <%= link_to 'Details', payment_path(payment.id } %>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>

#routes.rb
resources :payments, only: %i[index show]
```

With this code redirects me to an empty index page. How to make this link_to works without storing payments in db ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default in rails dynamic segment of the URL is `:id` but in `show` method you use `@payment = params[:payment]`

You can fix it 2 ways:

Try to catch `params[:id]`

```
def show
  @payment = params[:id]
end
```

Or another way: change dynamic segment name to `:payment`

```
resources :payments, only: %i[index show], param: :payment
```

In this case `params[:payment]` will be available